# Unexpected Behaviour with local variables and ToExpression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I encountered an unexpected behaviour in my mathematica-code, and want to understand whether that's a mathematica bug, or a misinterpretation on my side.

```
MainVar = 1;
Carrier = "MainVar";
f[] := (
  Module[{MainVar}, 
    MainVar = 3;
    Print[MainVar];
    Print[Carrier];
    Print[ToExpression[Carrier]]
])
f[] (* 3, MainVar, 1 *)
```

I would have expected that `Print[ToExpression[Carrier]]` gives me `3`, because `Carrier` points to `MainVar`, which has the value `3`.

When I use `MainVar` as global variable (as Eldo suggested below), I get the expected `3`. So my question is:

> Why does `ToExpression[Carrier]` give me `1` when I use `MainVar` as a local variable, even if both `MainVar` and `Carrier` have the correct values?

Comment: The local `MainVar` symbol "true name" isn't mainVar. Try removing the assignment `MainVar = 3;` to see it.

Comment: You can also put `Print[SymbolName@Unevaluated@MainVar]` inside the module to see what the real local name of `MainVar` is inside `Module`.

Comment: belisarius: wow i didnt know that. But I still dont understand why within the `Module`, Mathematica still uses the global one instead of the local one? I'm confused especially because `Print[MainVar]` uses the local one.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get the correct result while still keeping the `Module`. Might be fun to think about but I can't seem to find one method that would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start here:

- [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/121)

`Module` works by replacing explicit appearances of a given Symbol with a different one with a derived name, e.g.:

```
Module[{x}, x]
```

> ```
> x$715
> ```

Since `MainVar` appears nowhere in `Print[ToExpression[Carrier]]` the `Module` will not affect it.

A far simpler example of the same behavior that affects your case:

```
Module[{foo = 7}, ToExpression["foo"]]
```

> ```
> foo
> ```

If you were to use `Block` instead you would temporarily change the value of `MainVar` which will have the desired effect:

```
f[] :=
 Block[{MainVar},
   MainVar = 3;
   Print[MainVar];
   Print[Carrier];
   Print[ToExpression[Carrier]]
 ]

f[]
```

> 3
>
> MainVar
>
> 3

Comment: thanks, very interesting! Especially the hint to `Block`.

Comment: @NicoDean You're welcome.  See especially [WReach's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/121) in the linked Q&A; it is the most concise demonstration of `With`/`Module`/`Block` behavior I have seen.

Comment: already found that question and its answers some minutes ago. :)

Comment: @NicoDean Be careful though not to just blindly swap `Module` for `Block`.  See MrWizard's links and see how `Block` can unexpectedly bite you when used the wrong way ...

Comment: @NicoDean Very true what Szabolcs wrote!  When I was first using *Mathematica* I used `Block` all the time after somehow convincing myself it was "better" without actually understanding the ramifications of my action.  Don't make my mistake.

Comment: @NicoDean Thanks for the Accept!

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this behaviour is that `Module` does localization by renaming.  For example:

```
Module[{x}, x]
(* x$982 *)
```

That `x` inside `Module` is renamed to something like `x$nnn` with `nnn` being a different and unique number every time `Module` is evaluated.  `Module` will not be able to do the renaming inside any strings, so `ToExpression["MainVar"]` will evaluate to `MainVar` and not to `MainVar$nnn`.

We don't normally see these `x$nnn` forms because they have the [`Temporary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Temporary.html) attribute, which means that they automatically disappear as soon as they are not referenced any more (which is usually when the `Module` finishes evaluating).  They can however be easily *returned* from a `Module` as above.

---

General advice: avoid `ToExpression` if you can.  Mathematica expressions are flexible enough that it is almost never necessary to manipulate code as a string.  You can use held expressions instead.

Comment: Very interesting, especially to resolve my confusion about why i dont see the `$nnn`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another resource related to this question is the tutorial

> [How Modules Work](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/HowModulesWork.html)

It explains how, as others have pointed out, the symbol that is actually created in

```
Module[{x}, x]
```

is `x$nnn`, where `nnn` is the current value of `$ModuleNumber`.  `$ModuleNumber` is increased whenever `Module` is called (with local variables) and at other times.

---

There has been some curiosity about whether one can get at the local variable using `ToExpression`.  One can take advantage of `$ModuleNumber` to do this, but it is hard to imagine it would be worth working around the difficulties.  In every case, I would think it should be possible to avoid having to do this with little inconvenience.

So just to satisfy curiosity here is a way:

```
MainVar = 1;
Carrier = "MainVar";
f[] := Module[{MainVar},
  MainVar = 3;
  ToExpression[Carrier <> "$" <> ToString[$ModuleNumber - 1]]]

f[]
(* 3 *)
```

You have to subtract `1` from `$ModuleNumber` because it gets increased right after the variable(s) (only `MainVar` in this case) are instantiated.

But here's where it gets tricky.  You have to make sure that `$ModuleNumber` hasn't been increased when you use it.  Many internal functions use `Module`.  For instance, consider this:

```
MainVar = 1;
Carrier = "MainVar";
f[] := Module[{MainVar},
  Print[SymbolName@Unevaluated@MainVar];
  Print[$ModuleNumber];
  MainVar = Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}];
  Print[$ModuleNumber];
  ToExpression[Carrier <> "$" <> ToString[$ModuleNumber - 1]]]

f[]
(*
  Print: MainVar$328200
         328201
         328218
  Out[]= MainVar$328217
*)
```

One way to work with it is to store the current module number at the start:

```
MainVar = 1;
Carrier = "MainVar";
f[] := Module[{MainVar, myModuleNumber = $ModuleNumber},
  Print[myModuleNumber];
  Print[$ModuleNumber];
  MainVar = Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}];
  Print[$ModuleNumber];
  ToExpression[Carrier <> "$" <> ToString[myModuleNumber]]]

f[]
(*
  Print: 328221
         328222
         328229
  Out[]= 1/3
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to `$ModuleNumber`!